# Bar chart with multiple datasets - Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, razor, chart.js, bar-chart

I want to display a bar chart with multiple datasets as shown below,

[image]

I'm able to fetch the data as shown below

[image]

But how to convert this JSON array as below code. I need to show the attendance percentage for each shift for the last 7 days.

```
var barChartDataDaily = {
        labels: [@Html.Raw("'" + String.Join("','", (Model.GetWeeklyData.GroupBy(c => c.FormattedAccessDate).Select(c => c.First().FormattedAccessDate).ToList()))+"'" )],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "First Shift",
                backgroundColor: "#7F1E5E",
                borderColor: "#7F1E5E",
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [14, 27, 33, 46, 100, 67, 74]
            },
            {
                label: "Second Shift",
                backgroundColor: "#CE6D28",
                borderColor: "#CE6D28",
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [14, 27, 33, 46, 100, 67, 74]
            },
            {
                label: "Third Shift",
                backgroundColor: "#005486",
                borderColor: "#005486",
                borderWidth: 1,
                data: [100, 27, 34, 56, 69, 87, 73]
            }
        ]
    };
```

Appreciate your help with this. Thanks!

================= Edited ==================

```
//X-axis labels
var groupname = [@Html.Raw("'" + String.Join("','", (Model.GetWeeklyData.GroupBy(c => c.FormattedAccessDate).Select(c => c.First().FormattedAccessDate).ToList()))+"'" )];
 
//Fetched Array
var data = @Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.GetWeeklyData.ToList()))
```

Comment: can group the array based on the shiftName field. can u post the fetched aray

Comment: @cmgchess Hi, Thank you for your help! i have edited my question(Added the code for fetching array).Please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: Would be great to share you data as code snippet instead of image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you are successfully getting the data from the controller with

```js
var data = @Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.GetWeeklyData.ToList()))
```

You should group the data with the x-axis as the set of `FormattedAccessDate`.
In each `FormattedAccessDate`, there should be the bars for each `ShiftName` and its value as `AttendancePercentage`.

For the color settings (`backgroundColor` and `borderColor`), you can write the implementation to set the color value by the `ShiftName` or use the default color provided by the Chart.js via don't provide the values for `backgroundColor` and `borderColor`. It is optional.

```js
let labels = [...new Set(data.map(x => x.FormattedAccessDate))];
let datasets = data.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
  let shift = acc.find(x => x.label == cur.ShiftName);
  if (shift == null) {
    let color = '';
    
    switch (cur.ShiftName) {
      case 'First Shift':
        color = '#7F1E5E';
        break;
      case 'Second Shift':
        color = '#CE6D28';
        break;
      case 'Third Shift':
        color = '#005486';
        break;
    }
  
    shift = {
      label: cur.ShiftName,
      data: [cur.AttendancePercentage],
      backgroundColor: color,
      borderColor: color,
      borderWidth: 1
    };
    
    acc.push(shift);
  } else {
    shift.data.push(cur.AttendancePercentage);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

var barChartDataDaily = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasets
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
new Chart(ctx, barChartDataDaily);
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-w1nzkp?file=index.html)

Reference: [Vertical Bar Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/vertical.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works as expected.

Comment: How can i show datalabels on each bar. I am getting error when i used Chart.register function for calling ChartDataLabels. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you refer to the [documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration). Would be great if you can create another question post and provide the minimal code, error message. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Yong Shun, i have made the changes as per this documentation. I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193943/uncaught-typeerror-chart-register-is-not-a-function