# Uncaught TypeError: Chart.register is not a function

Tags: chart.js, bar-chart, chart.js-datalabels

I want to display datalables on top of eachbar(Datalabels are showing when i mouseover through the bar). I used chartdatalabels plugin to acheive this. But when i register the plugin using Chart.register(ChartDataLabels). Its throwing error and its not displaying the entire barchart.

Here is my code

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0-rc"></script>


var chartOptionsWeekly = {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'end',
                labels: {
                    value: {
                        color: 'white'
                    }
                }
             }
        },
        legend: {
            position: "top",
            labels: {
                fontColor: "white"
            }
        },
        title: {
            display: false,
            text: "Daily Trend"
        },        
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,                   
                    fontColor: 'white',
                    fontSize: 14,
                    stepSize: 20
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Attendance Percentage',
                    fontColor: 'white'
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    fontColor: 'white',
                    fontSize: 14
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Last 7 Days',
                    fontColor: 'white'
                }
            }]
        }
    }

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels)


window.onload = function () {        
        var ctxDaily = document.getElementById("barChartWeekly").getContext("2d");
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctxDaily, {
            type: "bar",
            plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
            data: barChartDataWeekly,            
            options: chartOptionsWeekly              
        });
        
    };
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Yong Shun "Uncaught TypeError: Chart.register is not a function" This was the error and it is not displaying any chart. You have not used Chart.register function in your code, do we need it? and i saw that window.onload function is commented. I have two charts in my page. Is it okay if i dont call the chart inside window.onload function?

Comment: Hi Teena, sorry for the previous demo. I notice that I am using the latest Chart.js, and found out that you are using the 2.8.0 version.

Comment: @Yong Shun is there anyway to show the datalabels with this 2.8.0 version?

Comment: From [here](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc), it state you  need the datalabel library with version 1.x if you use Chart.js v2.

Comment: @Yong Shun, This solved my pbm

Answer (score 1):

Note that you're using an outdated version of `Chart.js`, the current version is `4.4.0`.

`Chart.register` was introduced in `Chart.js` version 3, it replaced former `Chart.plugins.register` (see. [3.x Migration Guide -> Removed from Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html#removed-from-chart)).

To solve your problem, you should use `Chart.plugins.register` or even better, use the most recent version of `Chart.js`.