# Chartjs multiple bar using dynamic and variable JSON

Tags: json, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar graph based on json data that vary dynamically according to the filter.

I want the graph to show the TYPE related to the PERIOD, when it exists. If it doesn't don't show anything.

I was able to get the graph showing the data according to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074890/bar-chart-with-multiple-datasets-chart-js/77876213?noredirect=1#comment137291075_77876213) but it only works if all options for the data are availabe, which is not the case.

However, if a TYPE is missing from a PERIOD, it will shift back the TYPE into the previous PERIOD, which I don't want to.

Here's two examples

1. Two months with two types, but only 3 values (looks correct)

```
 [
    {
        "Period": "2023-12",
        "Total": 2238.86,
        "Type": "Drinks"
    },
    {
        "Period": "2023-12",
        "Total": 4672.35,
        "Type": "Food"
    },
    {
        "Period": "2024-01",
        "Total": 1166.5,
        "Type": "Drinks"
    }
]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EIx0.png)

2. Three months, three type, 4 values (data from second period shifted to the first period)

```
[
    {
        "Period": "2023-11",
        "Total": 2782.13,
        "Type": "Other"
    },
    {
        "Period": "2023-12",
        "Total": 2238.86,
        "Type": "Drinks"
    },
    {
        "Period": "2023-12",
        "Total": 4672.35,
        "Type": "Food"
    },
    {
        "Period": "2024-01",
        "Total": 1166.5,
        "Type": "Drinks"
    }
]
```

[data from second period shifted to the first period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttAwJ.png)

I've searched for days, tried different things but nothing seems to work.

This is the code that I'm using according to the topic mention earlier

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "../../ajax/barGraph.php?period=<?= $period; ?>",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(soldeInfo) {



          let labels = [...new Set(soldeInfo.map((x) => x.Period))];
          let datasets = soldeInfo.reduce(function (acc, cur) {
            let Type = acc.find((x) => x.label == cur.Type);
            if (Type == null) {
              let color = '';

              switch (cur.Type) {
                case 'Food':
                  color = 'red';
                  break;
                case 'Drinks':
                  color = 'green';
                  break;
                default:
                  color ='gray';
              }

              Type = {
                label: cur.Type,
                data: [cur.Total],
                backgroundColor: color,
                borderColor: color,
                borderWidth: 1,
              };

              acc.push(Type);
            } else {
              Type.data.push(cur.Total);
            }

            return acc;
          }, []);

          var soldeInfo = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
              labels: labels,
              datasets: datasets,
            },
          };

            const soldeChart = document.getElementById('chartSolde');
            new Chart(soldeChart, soldeInfo);



    }
});
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available values from each dataset are drawn at free positions from left to right.
Therefore, each `data` array must contain empty values at positions where no real value exists.

Please take a look at your amended and runnable code and see how this can be done.

```js
const soldeInfo = [
    { "Period": "2023-11", "Total": 2782.13, "Type": "Other" },
    { "Period": "2023-12", "Total": 2238.86, "Type": "Drinks" },
    { "Period": "2023-12", "Total": 4672.35, "Type": "Food" },
    { "Period": "2024-01", "Total": 1166.5, "Type": "Drinks" }
];

const colorOf = (type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'Food':
      return 'red';
    case 'Drinks':
      return 'green';
    default:
      return 'gray';
  }
}

let labels = [...new Set(soldeInfo.map((x) => x.Period))];
let datasets = soldeInfo.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  let type = acc.find((x) => x.label == cur.Type);
  if (type == null) {
    let color = colorOf(cur.Type);
    type = {
      label: cur.Type,
      data: new Array(labels.length).fill(0),
      backgroundColor: color,
      borderColor: color,
      borderWidth: 1,
    };
    acc.push(type);
  }
  type.data[labels.indexOf(cur.Period)] = cur.Total;  
  return acc;
}, []);

new Chart('chartSolde', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: datasets,
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
<canvas id="chartSolde" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks uminder, you're awesome. That's exactly that. :)